# Cyclic code not working on Drupal-7

Tags: php, jquery, drupal-7

I used slide.js file inside .info, following are the codes:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
 $( document ).ready(function( ) {
 $j('#block-block-29').cycle({
        slideResize: false,
        containerResize: true,
        fit: 0,
        fx: 'fade' // transition type
    });

 });
```

I put two images inside #block-block-29 and used proper CSS, they are supposed to shuffle but not behaving as required. 
I did many permutation and combination but no success, also included above codes directly inside html.tpl.php but still no result.

Answer (score 1):

> Use $j for document ready also. When you put jQuery into no-conflict
>   mode, you have the option of assigning a new variable name to replace
>   the $ alias.

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

 $j(document).ready(function( ) {

 $j('#block-block-29').cycle({
        slideResize: false,
        containerResize: true,
        fit: 0,
        fx: 'fade' // transition type
    });

 });
```

Comment: I tried but still not working. If I write code directly in a block in drupal it works but, if I include .js file inside .info file it does not work.